# REGEXP_REPLACE in ORACLE SQLLoader

Tags: regex, oracle, sql-loader

Can someone help me replacing value in text file using regexp_replace before storing data by SqlLoader?

My text file:

```
Andy     0001231231231
Bobby    0000032132132122
Charles  0000456456456
```

and expected result in DB are:

```
NAME     | PHONE
---------------------
Andy     | 1231231231
Bobby    | 32132132122
Charles  | 456456456
```

here is my sqlLoader file:

```
PHONE POSITION(10:45) NULLIF PHONE=BLANKS "REGEXP_REPLACE(:PHONE, '^0+([^0]\d+)$','\1')",
```

But, I still got the result like this:

```
NAME     | PHONE
---------------------
Andy     | 0001231231231
Bobby    | 0000032132132122
Charles  | 0000456456456
```

What's wrong with my SqlLoader file?

Thank you

Faizal

Comment: Note that the reason you got the original string back is because the regex did not find a match, so it just returned :PHONE.  This action can confuse you when first trying to get it working and results are not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `\` in every `\`. Finally the result is as I expected.